# ASP.Net Server Control Client Script

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to run a one off client side script from an asp.net server control?
I know you can use `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript()` on a normal page but obviously doesn't work on server control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use on `onClientClick="Javascript_FuncName"` attribute

sample

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="SAVE & SUBMIT" 
OnClick="BtnSave_Click" onClientClick="return CheckFunction"></asp:Button>
```

As you want to run your serverside code 1st then your client side, then at the end of server side code add this line

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Javascript", 
"javascript:FUNCTIONNAME(); ",   true);
```

If you using `UpdatePanel` then try like this

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Javascript", 
"javascript:FUNCTIONNAME(); ", true);
```

Comment: This will run before server code though, I need server code to be run first so need to trigger it from code behind.

Comment: then call your clientside funtion at the end of your serverside code

Comment: @user1166905: are you using UpdatePanel ?

Comment: Perfect, that last one did it although had to change like so:
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,GetType(), "Javascript", "javascript:displayMessageBox(); ", true);

Answer (score 1):

> I know you can use Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript() on a normal page but obviously doesn't work on server control.

Yes, it does work on a server control.  For example, you can call `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` in your server control's `OnPreRender` method.

Comment: Sorry yes it does there but I need to run it after a button click event on server side!